Draw a line on screen on Linux (or how it's done)
Disclaimer: I know there are already a bunch of questions about this topic, but I can't find any satisfactory explanations
I'm researching how graphics on Linux works. AFAIK, OpenGL essentially just provides the correct set of GPU instructions to draw some object. But how does talking to GPU really happen?
There is the DRM (Direct Rendering Manager), but I can't find any examples that would utilize hardware acceleration (most examples use dumb-buffers, which is not GPU-based, as these docs say.
I'm not even sure what I'm searching for. I want to make DRM draw something on screen, without OpenGL, without fancy high-level libraries. To ask a similar question: how are high-level libraries implemented? Are there any explanations so I don't have to interpret the whole source code by myself?

There isn't one way that something "really" happens, or one universal set of GPU instructions. Different hardware will have different instructions available, different modes of operation, and multiple ways of achieving the same thing. That's why the high-level libraries and APIs exist: to abstract away those details, so you can write code like "draw a line", rather than "if device is GeForce 40 Series, set mode to X, write to buffer Y, send update command Z; else if device is GeForce 30 Series, ...."

To put it bluntly, "how are high-level libraries implemented?" is like asking "how is a house built?" If it can be answered at all, it certainly wouldn't fit into the Answer box on this site.

Hm I see, thanks. But is there not even a single source about this? Like some textbook or docs or manpages or something? Or perhaps is there a way that I can just draw a line on my specific GPU? Where do I find this information?

I'm sure there are lots of sources, but somebody picking one at random probably won't be much use to you. Think about the house analogy - maybe someone will give you a beginner's guide to brick-laying, but what you were really interested in is laying concrete foundations; or they show you the building code for Nebraska, but you live in Uzbekistan. If you want a practical tutorial, it's going to be about some specific task, on some specific API (either the API for some specific hardware, or some standard abstraction).

This is like asking "how are bytes written to files on disk". You don't access the disk directly, you use the filesystem. And you don't access the display directly, you use graphics libraries.

The question "how can I use DRM to draw a line on the screen" would be answerable - although it would also probably be closed as "needs more effort", since you can probably find a guide to try something, and then ask a more specific debugging question.
